# Programmatically Lighten a Color

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic, colors

**Motivation**

I'd like to find a way to take an arbitrary color and lighten it a few shades, so that I can programatically create a nice gradient from the one color to a lighter version. The gradient will be used as a background in a UI.

**Possibility 1**

Obviously I can just split out the RGB values and increase them individually by a certain amount. Is this actually what I want?

**Possibility 2**

My second thought was to convert the RGB to HSV/HSB/HSL (Hue, Saturation, Value/Brightness/Lightness), increase the brightness a bit, decrease the saturation a bit, and then convert it back to RGB. Will this have the desired effect in general?

Comment: If the background is white, then modifying alpha/transparency can often work well as a hack to "lighten" the color.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would go for the second option. Generally speaking the RGB space is not really good for doing color manipulation (creating transition from one color to an other, lightening / darkening a color, etc). Below are two sites I've found with a quick search to convert from/to RGB to/from HSL:

- [from the "Fundamentals of Computer Graphics"](http://marcocorvi.altervista.org/games/imgpr/rgb-hsl.htm)
- [some sourcecode in C#](http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm) - should be easy to adapt to other programming languages.

Comment: Good replacement link for conversion source code: http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx

Comment: Another reference link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f05428dd-b471-4c47-b52e-55449b6bf6a1/rgbhsb-color-conversion

Comment: Update 2021: The first link of Curtis Yallop no longer works and the second refers only to further links. So this is a step by step programming receipt: https://css-tricks.com/converting-color-spaces-in-javascript/ And here are wonderful insights what is behind the conversion of color spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147465/818827 - I ended up with the second option of the OP, after fiddling around with handy, simple approaches which have their unwelcome limits.

Answer (score 64):

As [Wedge said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141855/programmatically-lighten-a-color#141865), you want to multiply to make things brighter, but that only works until one of the colors becomes saturated (i.e. hits 255 or greater).  At that point, you can just clamp the values to 255, but you'll be subtly changing the hue as you get lighter.  To keep the hue, you want to maintain the ratio of (middle-lowest)/(highest-lowest).

Here are two functions in Python. The first implements the naive approach which just clamps the RGB values to 255 if they go over. The second redistributes the excess values to keep the hue intact.

```
def clamp_rgb(r, g, b):
    return min(255, int(r)), min(255, int(g)), min(255, int(b))

def redistribute_rgb(r, g, b):
    threshold = 255.999
    m = max(r, g, b)
    if m <= threshold:
        return int(r), int(g), int(b)
    total = r + g + b
    if total >= 3 * threshold:
        return int(threshold), int(threshold), int(threshold)
    x = (3 * threshold - total) / (3 * m - total)
    gray = threshold - x * m
    return int(gray + x * r), int(gray + x * g), int(gray + x * b)
```

I created a gradient starting with the RGB value (224,128,0) and multiplying it by 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, etc. up to 2.0. The upper half is the result using `clamp_rgb` and the bottom half is the result with `redistribute_rgb`. I think it's easy to see that redistributing the overflows gives a much better result, without having to leave the RGB color space.

[image: Lightness gradient with clamping (top) and redistribution (bottom)]

For comparison, here's the same gradient in the HLS and HSV color spaces, as implemented by Python's [`colorsys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) module. Only the `L` component was modified, and clamping was performed on the resulting RGB values. The results are similar, but require color space conversions for every pixel.

[image: Lightness gradient with HLS (top) and HSV (bottom)]

Comment: After upvoting this I realized this is way overkill.  All you need to do is alpha blend with white at a certain opacity (i.e. interpolate the color components the same fraction towards 255).

Comment: @Andy take a look at the sample. The first two boxes on the left don't have any white in them, they're fully saturated. It would have been more if I had started with a darker color.

Comment: Ah, I see, so your code has the same linear discontinuity as the HLS colorspace.  I can see how that would make a richer gradient.  Since I just wanted to lighten a color for a hover highlight instead of making a gradient, I was expecting a simpler method

Comment: @Andy there's another answer that suggests a linear interpolation with white, I believe that's exactly what you're after.

Comment: Yes, I was going to add that answer myself until I saw someone else had done it.  Cheers!

Comment: Why do you return the color as is if the maximum component is less than or equal to 255.999? This condition is true for all possible valid colors.

Comment: @Jordan multiplying the RGB values can result in components that are greater than 255, so they aren't valid anymore.  The challenge is to convert them to valid values, and this answer contrasts two ways of doing that.

Comment: @MarkRansom, right but you are returning whenever the max component is less than or equal to 255.999. Not when greater. My point is that the way `redistribute_rgb` is defined, it will always just return the same color you give it, unless that color is invalid. It seems backwards.

Comment: @Jordan if all the components are valid then there's no work to do so you can just return them immediately. It's only when a component is greater than 255.999 that you need to make adjustments. `clamp_rgb` could have the same `if` but it's so simple it wouldn't benefit from it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I'm saying there is a bug in your code. `m` is the maximum component. You return if the condition `m <= threshold` is true where the maximum component _is less than_ 255.999. This condition will be true for _every_ valid color. So for every valid color, you return the color as is. Only for invalid colors do you lighten the color.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Oh! You are expecting invalid colors. I see! Sorry. Carry on.

Answer (score 27):

In C#:

```
public static Color Lighten(Color inColor, double inAmount)
{
  return Color.FromArgb(
    inColor.A,
    (int) Math.Min(255, inColor.R + 255 * inAmount),
    (int) Math.Min(255, inColor.G + 255 * inAmount),
    (int) Math.Min(255, inColor.B + 255 * inAmount) );
}
```

I've used this all over the place.

Comment: Very handy, and simple.  Using it in a VB.NET app now.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801406/c-create-a-lighter-darker-color-based-on-a-system-color

Comment: If you are using `using System.Windows.Media.Color;` shouldn't you be casting to byte ?

Answer (score 11):

ControlPaint class in System.Windows.Forms namespace has static methods Light and Dark:

```
public static Color Dark(Color baseColor, float percOfDarkDark);
```

These methods use private implementation of HLSColor. I wish this struct was public and in System.Drawing.

Alternatively, you can use GetHue, GetSaturation, GetBrightness on Color struct to get HSB components. Unfortunately, I didn't find the reverse conversion.

Answer (score 9):

Convert it to RGB and linearly interpolate between the original color and the target color (often white).  So, if you want 16 shades between two colors, you do:

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
  colors[i].R = start.R + (i * (end.R - start.R)) / 15;
  colors[i].G = start.G + (i * (end.G - start.G)) / 15;
  colors[i].B = start.B + (i * (end.B - start.B)) / 15;
}
```

Comment: In most cases only the start and end color are needed since the graphics library of choice probably has built in gradient capabilities.

Comment: And by using integer division, you eliminate the need for round (floor). Clever.

Answer (score 7):

In order to get a lighter or a darker version of a given color you should modify its brightness. You can do this easily even without converting your color to HSL or HSB color. For example to make a color lighter you can use the following code:

```
float correctionFactor = 0.5f;
float red = (255 - color.R) * correctionFactor + color.R;
float green = (255 - color.G) * correctionFactor + color.G;
float blue = (255 - color.B) * correctionFactor + color.B;
Color lighterColor = Color.FromArgb(color.A, (int)red, (int)green, (int)blue);
```

If you need more details, [read the full story on my blog](http://www.pvladov.com/2012/09/make-color-lighter-or-darker.html).

Comment: +1, Nicks method, the correct way. But you can still skip the cast to and from float by doing it like Adam Rosenfield, by splitting the correction factor into steps and index, which also gives two understandable values instead of one abstract number between 0.0 and 1.0. e.g. your correction factor is Rosenfield's  i/15, while assuming white as target color.

Answer (score 4):

Converting to HS(LVB), increasing the brightness and then converting back to RGB is the only way to reliably lighten the colour without effecting the hue and saturation values (ie to only lighten the colour without changing it in any other way).

Answer (score 3):

A very similar question, with useful answers, was asked previously:
[How do I determine darker or lighter color variant of a given color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97646/how-do-i-determine-darker-or-lighter-color-variant-of-a-given-color)

Short answer: multiply the RGB values by a constant if you just need "good enough", translate to HSV if you require accuracy.

Comment: Upvoted for the reference to the similar question, but I disagree with the RGB advice - go HSV.

Answer (score 3):

I used Andrew's answer and Mark's answer to make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ySGm2/1/) (as of 1/2013 no range input for ff).

```
function calcLightness(l, r, g, b) {
    var tmp_r = r;
    var tmp_g = g;
    var tmp_b = b;

    tmp_r = (255 - r) * l + r;
    tmp_g = (255 - g) * l + g;
    tmp_b = (255 - b) * l + b;

    if (tmp_r > 255 || tmp_g > 255 || tmp_b > 255) 
        return { r: r, g: g, b: b };
    else 
        return { r:parseInt(tmp_r), g:parseInt(tmp_g), b:parseInt(tmp_b) }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've done this both ways -- you get much better results with Possibility 2.

Any simple algorithm you construct for Possibility 1 will probably work well only for a limited range of starting saturations.

You would want to look into Poss 1 if (1) you can restrict the colors and brightnesses used, and (2) you are performing the calculation a lot in a rendering.

Generating the background for a UI won't need very many shading calculations, so I suggest Poss 2.

-Al.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to produce a gradient fade-out, I would suggest the following optimization: Rather than doing RGB->HSB->RGB for each individual color you should only calculate the target color. Once you know the target RGB, you can simply calculate the intermediate values in RGB space without having to convert back and forth. Whether you calculate a linear transition of use some sort of curve is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Convert RGB to HSL, adjust HSL, convert back to RGB.

Method 2: *Lerp* the RGB colour values - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerp_(computing)

See [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97646/how-do-i-determine-darker-or-lighter-color-variant-of-a-given-color/2690026#2690026) for a C# implementation of method 2.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend that you alpha blended to white:

```
oneMinus = 1.0 - amount
r = amount + oneMinus * r
g = amount + oneMinus * g
b = amount + oneMinus * b
```

where `amount` is from 0 to 1, with 0 returning the original color and 1 returning white.

You might want to blend with whatever the background color is if you are lightening to display something disabled:

```
oneMinus = 1.0 - amount
r = amount * dest_r + oneMinus * r
g = amount * dest_g + oneMinus * g
b = amount * dest_b + oneMinus * b
```

where `(dest_r, dest_g, dest_b)` is the color being blended to and `amount` is from 0 to 1, with zero returning `(r, g, b)` and 1 returning `(dest.r, dest.g, dest.b)`

Comment: I think this should be the top answer.  Likewise to darken you just alpha blend to black (i.e. multiply components by some `amount < 1`).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find this question until after it became a related question to my original question.

However, using insight from these great answers. I pieced together a nice two-liner function for this:

[Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color/13542669#13542669)

Its a version of method 1. But with over saturation taken into account. Like Keith said in his answer above; use Lerp to seemly solve the same problem Mark mentioned, but without redistribution. The results of `shadeColor2` should be much closer to doing it the right way with HSL, but without the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but if you use `javascript` or `nodejs`, you can use [tinycolor library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinycolor2), and manipulate the color the way you want:

```
tinycolor("red").lighten().desaturate().toHexString() // "#f53d3d"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried number #1 first, but #2 sounds pretty good. Try doing it yourself and see if you're satisfied with the results, it sounds like it'll take you maybe 10 minutes to whip up a test.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I don't think either is correct, but I believe you want a variant of option #2.  The problem being that taken RGB 990000 and "lightening" it would really just add onto the Red channel (Value, Brightness, Lightness) until you got to FF.  After that (solid red), it would be taking down the *saturation* to go all the way to solid white.

The conversions get annoying, especially since you can't go direct to and from RGB and Lab, but I think you really want to separate the chrominance and luminence values, and just modify the luminence to really achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of lightening an RGB colour in Python:

```
def lighten(hex, amount):
    """ Lighten an RGB color by an amount (between 0 and 1),

    e.g. lighten('#4290e5', .5) = #C1FFFF
    """
    hex = hex.replace('#','')
    red = min(255, int(hex[0:2], 16) + 255 * amount)
    green = min(255, int(hex[2:4], 16) + 255 * amount)
    blue = min(255, int(hex[4:6], 16) + 255 * amount)
    return "#%X%X%X" % (int(red), int(green), int(blue))
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea of what this does.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Mark Ransom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141943/1262865).

Where the `clampRGB` function tries to maintain the hue, it however miscalculates the scaling to keep the same luminance. This is because the calculation directly uses sRGB values which are not linear.

Here's a Java version that does the same as `clampRGB` (although with values ranging from 0 to 1) that maintains luminance as well:

```
private static Color convertToDesiredLuminance(Color input, double desiredLuminance) {
  if(desiredLuminance > 1.0) {
    return Color.WHITE;
  }
  if(desiredLuminance < 0.0) {
    return Color.BLACK;
  }

  double ratio = desiredLuminance / luminance(input);
  double r = Double.isInfinite(ratio) ? desiredLuminance : toLinear(input.getRed()) * ratio;
  double g = Double.isInfinite(ratio) ? desiredLuminance : toLinear(input.getGreen()) * ratio;
  double b = Double.isInfinite(ratio) ? desiredLuminance : toLinear(input.getBlue()) * ratio;

  if(r > 1.0 || g > 1.0 || b > 1.0) {  // anything outside range?
    double br = Math.min(r, 1.0);  // base values
    double bg = Math.min(g, 1.0);
    double bb = Math.min(b, 1.0);
    double rr = 1.0 - br;  // ratios between RGB components to maintain
    double rg = 1.0 - bg;
    double rb = 1.0 - bb;

    double x = (desiredLuminance - luminance(br, bg, bb)) / luminance(rr, rg, rb);

    r = 0.0001 * Math.round(10000.0 * (br + rr * x));
    g = 0.0001 * Math.round(10000.0 * (bg + rg * x));
    b = 0.0001 * Math.round(10000.0 * (bb + rb * x));
  }

  return Color.color(toGamma(r), toGamma(g), toGamma(b));
}
```

And supporting functions:

```
private static double toLinear(double v) {  // inverse is #toGamma
  return v <= 0.04045 ? v / 12.92 : Math.pow((v + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4);
}

private static double toGamma(double v) {  // inverse is #toLinear
  return v <= 0.0031308 ? v * 12.92 : 1.055 * Math.pow(v, 1.0 / 2.4) - 0.055;
}

private static double luminance(Color c) {
  return luminance(toLinear(c.getRed()), toLinear(c.getGreen()), toLinear(c.getBlue()));
}

private static double luminance(double r, double g, double b) {
  return r * 0.2126 + g * 0.7152 + b * 0.0722;
}
```