# Highcharts: Fade other columns when mouse over one column

Tags: highcharts

In a column chart, I want to face other columns on mouse overing on one column.

Another advanced version of this that I am trying to achieve is in case of stacked column chart. Fade everything apart from the stack on which mouse is over.

Comment: Have you created at least the non-advanced version of this? How are you fading it? Any code to share?

Comment: Nope. Not able to achieve simpler version as well.

Comment: It would be good with some attempt here, if only to see what paths you've attempted. But in both scenarios here you are interesting in only having the exact `Point` highlighted, not the entire `Series`?

Comment: Yes, please can you at least give us a fiddle of a column chart so we can have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supplying code to begin with so I'll try to be as specific as possible in my solution. You want to start by creating a mouseOver event which is triggered when you hover over any of your columns. This event will identify the column being hovered. You then trigger a function which 'fades' all series EXCEPT the hovered one. The fading can be done by grabbing the original colors of the columns and increasing the [brightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317452/hex-colour-formula-to-make-it-brigter). Then on loss of hovering, return to the original brightness.

If you provide us with a fiddle, we will be able to give you a more specific response but please attempt the task yourself.