# Generate colors with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors

I want to add functionality to my application that randomly generates a color scheme based on some color, for example #0080C8. So, when I click a button, it takes the base color and generates a list of colors, each generated with its own parameter, for example, lighten by 20% for one, and darken by 10% for another one.
So, what I wonder about, is there a ready-to-use JS library that has such methods like darken, lighten, and so on?

Comment: Why not just use HSL colors ? things like darker -20%, or lighter +10% are trivial within it.

Comment: Also see this answer of  mine for some javascript code [Darken/lightenin javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801406/c-create-a-lighter-darker-color-based-on-a-system-color/801463#801463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this JQuery plugin:

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/

Answer (score 0):

color blender is an oldie but a goodie. i love it. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/