# How to generate a color for special number

Tags: javascript, colors, generator

how can I generate a color for special number with javascript, so that for example for number 3 I get the same color every time, for number 6 another color.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array, store each color you need in it, and then access by index:

```
// declare color array
var colors = [ "#fff", "#f00", "#0f0", "#00f" ]; // put every color you need

// access the colors
var white = colors[0];
var red = colors[1];
// and so on...
```

**EDIT**

Arrays in JavaScript are dynamic, so you can add colors at runtime:

```
colors.push("#000"); // add black color
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answers but the count of colors is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
var colorNum = 2;
var colors = [
    "blue",
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "black"
];
```

Where `colors[colorNum]` is "yellow".

You can just reference `colors` (an array) and index it by using an integer (any integer from 0 to the length of the array) to get the associated color.

Comment: @BorisAghajanian So show what you're already doing/using, otherwise it's too hard to understand what you need/want.

Answer (score 1):

### Do you want N distinct colours?

You could use HSL colours as in: http://jsfiddle.net/duw6n/5/

```
function mod(num, den) {
    return Math.abs(num) % den;
}

function hue(n, k) {
    var tau = 360.0,
        k = k || 1;

    return mod((tau / n) * k, tau);
}

function gen_colours(lst) {
    return lst.map(function (c) {
        var node = $('<div/>').addClass('colour');

        node.html(c)
            .css({'background-color': 'hsl(' + hue(lst.length, c) + ', 100%, 50%)'});

        return node;
    });
}
```

Also see [Generate colors with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594040/generate-colors-with-javascript) for JS libraries handling colours.