# Colors: White if background is DARK and BLACK when is LIGHT

Tags: .net, gdi+

I draw some text in a custom Label.

User can modify the label background, but the control shoud accomodate the text visibility in dependence of the specified background.

So, when the background is DARK I want to draw white foreground text, when its LIGHT I want BLACK foreground.

How to "understand" if the color is LIGHT or DARK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97646/how-do-i-determine-darker-or-lighter-color-variant-of-a-given-color/97697#97697

Comment: @KMån: I don't need a darker or lighter variant of a color. I need to detect if a given color is light or dark by itself.

Comment: You might want to accept your own answer. Using a predefined function is clearly better than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to add the color componets of the background color and compare them to a threshold.

You might want to give blue a lower weight. `0.3*R+0.6*G+0.1*B` is a common choice.

Answer (score 2):

use [`Color.GetBrightness()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness.aspx)